# Atomic Transactions not working in Django

Tags: django, transactions, atomic

I have a Django function which does a very basic create/update operation and I was trying to implement atomic block for transactions but it doesn't seem to work. The implementation is very straight forward but I am still unable to do the rollback so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or missed some config.

```
    with transaction.atomic():
       try:
          auth_user_data['email'] = email
          auth_user_data['first_name'] = first_name
          auth_user_data['last_name'] = last_name
          user = User.objects.using('xyz').create(**auth_user_data)


          auth_user_data['id'] = user.id
          user_securities_data['zipcode'] = address_info['zipcode']
          user_securities_data['address'] = address_info['address']
          user_securities_data['country'] = address_info['country']
          user_securities_data['user_id'] = user.id
          user_securities_data['abc'] = user.id


          user = Profile.objects.using('xyz').create(**user_securities_data)

      except Exception as e:
         print("ERROR___________", e)
```

What I am trying to achieve here is the first create to the DB should be success and the second create DB should be a failure and that would revert both the operations.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you're attempting to create twice, and how it doesn't work?

Comment: Does the print in the exception get triggered? If so, the rollback doesn't happen because the exception got swallowed. Try raising the exception again after the print

Comment: @foxpal 

user = User.objects.using('xyz').create(**auth_user_data)
user = Profile.objects.using('xyz').create(**user_securities_data)

In the posted code block I have these 2 lines which is creating an entry in the DB.
If you ask me how am i creating an exception then the answer to that is am trying to add a data into a column which doesn't exists for the latter creation.

And to answer what is not working is the entry is stored in the 1st table, which ideally under atomic block shouldn't have commited and i shouldn't have seen the entry if it was rolled back.

Comment: @BrianDestura Yes the print exception did get triggered. I did try raising an exception again after the print as you suggested but that didn't work aswell. I have tried without try catch block aswell and that doesn't seem to work aswell.